# How to read specific file fstream?

Tags: c++

I have a `data.txt` file, and its contents are:

```
[exe1]

1 0 2 9 3 8
----------


[exe2]


----------
10 2 9 3 8:0
```

I want to read line 2: `1 0 2 9 3 8`. But my output is only `1`.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>
#include<string>

std::fstream& GotoLine(std::fstream& file, unsigned int num) {
    file.seekg(std::ios::beg);
    for (int i = 0; i < num - 1; ++i) {
        file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    return file;
}

int main() {


        using namespace std;
        fstream file("data.txt");

        GotoLine(file, 2);

        std::string line2;
        file >> line2;

        std::cout << line2;
        cin.get();
        return 0;

}
```

What is my problem? Sorry, I'm new in programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file >> line2;` will stop reading a the first white space and hence reads only "1" because the extraction `operator >>` uses space as a deliminator.

you may want to use `getline` as `getline(file,line2)`

Answer (score 2):

The input operator `>>` reads *space delimited* strings, if you want to read a whole line you need to use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
std::string line2;
std::getline(file, line);
```